# How can I produce an appropriate plot and fit a logistic regression model using the given data in R?

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression

```
pesticide <- data.frame(dose=factor(c("high", "medium", "low")),
                       affected=c(50, 25, 1),
                       total=c(100, 49, 59))
```

This is the data given to us in a tutorial. I really don't know how to start visualising it as I don't know if the appropriate plot that the tutorial exercise is asking is a normal box plot or a scatter/jitter plot. Here's my attempt on fitting a logistic regression:

```
mod <- glm(cbind(affected, total-affected) ~ 1 + dose, data= pesticide, family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

I'm not sure if I fitted the logistic regression correctly. The aim of this question is to investigate the survivability of pest on various concentration of pesticide.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I appreciate that you've demonstrated some effort here (i.e. the `glm()` fit), but if you don't understand what the tutorial exercise is asking for maybe the first place to go to clarify is to your instructor or TA ... ???

Comment: @BenBolker I tried. Still waiting for an answer for two days now. I'm a distant learner and the instructor is technology challenged.